# How to apply Azure Information Protection labels to an Outlook email using Access VBA?

Tags: vba, ms-access, outlook, azure-information-protection

I have a VBA function in our MS Access database that generates Outlook emails and sends them from a shared inbox.

Our company uses Azure Information Protection to protect documents. A label needs to be applied to each email before it is sent (e.g. Public, Business Sensitive, Internal).

Rather than having the user click the label 25 times as it pops up for each email, I am trying to apply it programmatically.

I get error code (-1248837627).

My solution was to grab the labels GUID and then apply it to the email as below. I came across other solutions such as using SendKeys but I prefer it to be a last resort.

```vb
With olMail
   .To = olSendTo
   .Subject = olSubject
   .PermissionTemplateGuid = "XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXX"
   .Permission = olPermissionTemplate
   'And so on, the email function works great until the above two lines are added
```

Am I applying the `.Permissions` or `.PermissionTemplateGUID` improperly?

I have seen a similar approach to apply labels to Excel documents (grabbing and setting the guid).

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted is used to specify Information Rights Management (IRM) permissions. Azure Information Protection is another story.

You need to add a user property in the following format:

```
"MSIP_Label_" & guid_internal_use_only & "_Enabled"
```

But I'd suggest exploring internals of Outlook mail items using [MFCMAPI](https://github.com/stephenegriffin/mfcmapi) or `OutlookSpy` to find the exact solution. Try to set it manually then explore internals using these tools.